# Elegant way to use regex to match order-indifferent groups of characters while limiting how may times a given character can appear?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to use python regular expressions to match groups of characters with limits on how many times a character can appear in the match. The main problem is that the order of characters does not matter.

I would like to find a simple and extensible pattern for saying things like:

- Find 3 characters together.
- All of the characters must be from the group 'ABC'
- 0 to 3 of them can be 'A'
- 0 to 3 of them can be 'B'
- 0 to 1 of them can be 'C'

In which case the following would match:

ABC ACB CBA BCA AAB ABA BAA AAC ACA CAA ABB BAB BBA BBB

and the following would not match:

CCC CCA CAC ACC CCB CBC BCC

I have tried several approaches using lookahead but have yet to find one that handles all cases.  For instance:

```
(?=C?[AB]{2,3})(?=[AB]{2,3}C?)(?=[AB]C?[AB])([ABC]{3})
```

which you can [see here at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aU6gF1/1).

*Is there a pattern for this type of match that doesn't involve listing all possible combinations?*

**UPDATE**: Thank you for the great answers. You expanded my understanding of regular expressions. Since the original question didn't specify whether I wanted to match a substring and gave examples that implied to the contrary. I will select the answer most in line with spirit of the original question and post a new question specific to the substring issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use regexes? It only takes a couple lines to write a function that would be a lot easier to comprehend than one of these awful regexes.

Comment: That's a good point. Unfortunately to code has to integrate with a larger regex pattern. Unless there is a way to escape to a python function from a regex.

Comment: @sln The 3 case works great but the 4 case won't work as a substring. Check this out http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(?!.?C.?C)([ABC]{3})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/107)

---

to match a substring use this pattern

```
(?!CC.|C.C|.CC)([ABC]{3})
```

---

for ABCD with A{0,4} B{0,4} C{0,2} D{0,1} use this pattern

```
(?!([ABD]?C){3}|([ABC]?D){2})([ABCD]{4})
```

Comment: This won't match `ACB` in `ACBC`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski this matches `ACB`??!! and should not match `ACBC` per the OP's criteria

Comment: You rock! Can you generalize it for larger sets?  Ie. ABCD with A{0,4} B{0,4} C{0,2} D{0,1}?

Comment: @Colin You didn't specify whether the 3 characters can be immediately surrounded by other characters. If they can, this answer wouldn't for instance match `ACB` if it's immediately followed by a `C`. I was just pointing out that the lookahead can match 4 characters and *overflow* from the full match string.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I see. I didn't test for that but it is an issue.  Is there a way around that problem?

Comment: @Colin, updated my answer above, was the intent to find whole strings or sub-strings?

Comment: @alphabravo This my bad, the question doesn't specify.  Ideally it should match a sub-string.

Comment: @alphabravo It doesn't match eg AABDDD, it should get the first four characters AABD- http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/6

Comment: Amazing, I think you got it and it's easy to extend.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?!(.*?C){2})[ABC]{3}
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aU6gF1/2

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?!(.*?C){2})[ABC]{3}', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"ABC\nACB\nCBA\nBCA\nAAB\nABA\nBAA\nAAC\nACA\nCAA\nABB\nBAB\nBBA\nBBB\nCCC\nCCA\nCAC\nACC\nCCB\nCBC\nBCC\n\n\n\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is programmatically generate an explicit alternation that you can then embed in other regexes:

```
from collections import Counter, namedtuple
from itertools import product

# You could just hardcode tuples in `limits` instead and access their indices in 
# `test`; I just happen to like `namedtuple`.
Limit = namedtuple('Limit', ['low', 'high'])

# conditions
length = 3
valid_characters = 'ABC'
limits = {
    'A': Limit(low=0, high=3),
    'B': Limit(low=0, high=3),
    'C': Limit(low=0, high=1)
    }

# determines whether a single string is valid
def is_valid(string):
    if len(string) != length:
        return False
    counts = Counter(string)
    for character in limits:
        if not (limits[character].low <= counts[character] <= limits[character].high):
            return False
    return True

# constructs a (foo|bar|baz)-style alternation of all valid strings
def generate_alternation():
    possible_strings = map(''.join,
                           product(valid_characters, repeat=length))
    valid_strings = filter(is_valid,
                           possible_strings)
    alternation = '(' + '|'.join(valid_strings) + ')'
    return alternation
```

Given the conditions I included above, `generate_alternation()` would give:

```
(AAA|AAB|AAC|ABA|ABB|ABC|ACA|ACB|BAA|BAB|BAC|BBA|BBB|BBC|BCA|BCB|CAA|CAB|CBA|CBB)
```

Which would do what you wanted. You can embed the resulting alternation in further regexes freely.

Comment: Nice, I might have to go this way to avoid the overmatch problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the permutation approach.
http://regex101.com/r/kO4uW8/1

```
 #  (?!(C.?C)|.?CC)[ABC]{3}

 (?!
      ( C .? C )
   |  .? CC
 )
 [ABC]{3}
```

Comment: If you want to solve in the context of substring I opened a specific post here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811192/elegant-way-to-use-regex-to-match-order-indifferent-groups-of-characters-in-a-s