# Elegant way to use regex to match order-indifferent groups of characters (in a substring) while limiting how may times a given character can appear?

Tags: python, regex

This is a follow-on to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810021/elegant-way-to-use-regex-to-match-order-indifferent-groups-of-characters-while-l).  This question amends the question to the original intent and increases complexity by adding the requirement that the regex **work with substrings**.

I am looking for a way to use python regular expressions to match groups of characters with limits on how many times a character can appear in the match. The main problem is that the order of characters does not matter.

I would like to find a simple and extensible pattern for saying things like:

- Find 4 characters together.
- All of the characters must be from the group 'ABCD'
- 0 to 4 of them can be 'A'
- 0 to 3 of them can be 'B'
- 0 to 3 of them can be 'C'
- 0 to 1 of them can be 'D'

In which case the following substrings match:

AAAA AAAB AAAC AAAD AABA AABB AABC AABD AACA AACB AACC AACD AADA AADB AADC ABAA ABAB ABAC ABAD ABBA ABBB ABBC ABBD...

and the following substrings would not match:

CCCC DDDD DDDA DDAA DDAB ...

I put the [match list here](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/3).

*Is there a pattern for this type of match that doesn't involve listing all possible combinations?*

Comment: I think this is fraught with permutation nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern to match your criteria as a sub-string

```
(?!B{4})(?!C{4})(?!([ABC]?D){2})[A-D]{4}
```

```
(?!B{4})            # does not see 4B's
(?!C{4})            # does not see 4C's
(?!([ABC]?D){2})    # does not see 2D's in any order
[A-D]{4}            # [A-D] 4 times
```

---

Edit:
After reading comments below, give this pattern a try:

```
(?!B{4})(?!C{4})((?!.?.?DD|.?D.D|D..D)[A-D]{4})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/19)

Comment: Wow. I think you might have it.

Comment: @Colin how is this correct. it is not working here http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/15

Comment: @vks You are right, but alphabravo answered on a different thread and we both got confused (it was very late).  I think it works -- (?!([ABD]?C){3}|([ABC]?D){2})([ABCD]{4})

Comment: updated above, may need some extensive testing, thanks @vks for reporting false matching.

Comment: I extended the test cases, looks good.  All of the valid and invalid strings are listed and a variety of extensions to the strings... not every case but many.  http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/20

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!(.{2}?D{2,}))(?!(.{3}?B{4,}))(?!(.{3}?C{4,}))[ABCD]{4}
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/17

Comment: Looks great, easy to understand and extend.  I don't think it works with substrings -- http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/5.

Comment: @Colin when its more than 4 characters what should be the result?

Comment: It should match the first substring that meets the constraints.

Comment: It gets all the matches but also some of the don't matches - http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/18